# Split a pandas dataframe column into multiple and iterate through it

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to take a artist with matching id that make music across various singular to combinations of genres.

**This is what I am trying to do**

```
Artist | Id | Genre                | Jazz | Blues | Rock | Trap | Rap | Hip-Hop | Pop | Rb  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob    | 1  | [Jazz, Blues]        |   1  |   1   |   0  |   0  |   0 |   0     |  0  |   0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fred   | 2  | [Rock,Jazz]          |   1  |   0   |   1  |   0  |   0 |   0     | 0   |   0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jeff   | 3  | [Trap, Rap, Hip-Hop] |   0  |   0   |   0  |   1  |   1 |   1     | 0   |   0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Amy    | 4  | [Pop, Rock, Jazz]    |   1  |   0   |   1  |   0  |   0 |   0     | 1   |   0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mary   | 5  | [Hip-Hop, Jazz, Rb]  |   1  |   0   |   0  |   0  |   0 |   1     | 0   |   1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**this is the error i get**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-7a4ed81e14d7> in <module>
     11 for index, row in artist_df.iterrows():
     12     x.append(index)
---> 13     for i in row['genre']:
     14         artists_with_genres.at[index, genre] = 1
     15 

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

These (artists) genres are attributes I will use to help to determine a similar artists when combined with other factors like years, songs or demographics.

The new columns I am creating and iterating through will specify whether a artist is in a genre. With 1/0 to simply represent whether the artist is rock/hip-hop/trap etc. or not. using binary representation of attributes.

**this is the current dataframe**

[image]

Took my data frame and split the genres into individual so I can convert to 1/0 binary representation.

Do I need to set genre to the index?

**1st took data frame like this**

```
Artist | Id | Genre               |
--------------------------------------
Bob    |  1 | Jazz | Blues
--------------------------------------
Fred   |  2 | Rock | Jazz
--------------------------------------
Jeff   |  3 | Trap | Rap | Hip-Hop
--------------------------------------
Amy    |  4 | Pop | Rock | Jazz
--------------------------------------
Mary   |  5 | Hip-Hop | Jazz | Rb
```

**This is what I am trying to do**

```
Artist | Id | Genre                | Jazz | Blues | Rock | Trap | Rap | Hip-Hop | Pop | Rb  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob    | 1  | [Jazz, Blues]        |   1  |   1   |   0  |   0  |   0 |   0     |  0  |   0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fred   | 2  | [Rock,Jazz]          |   1  |   0   |   1  |   0  |   0 |   0     | 0   |   0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jeff   | 3  | [Trap, Rap, Hip-Hop] |   0  |   0   |   0  |   1  |   1 |   1     | 0   |   0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Amy    | 4  | [Pop, Rock, Jazz]    |   1  |   0   |   1  |   0  |   0 |   0     | 1   |   0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mary   | 5  | [Hip-Hop, Jazz, Rb]  |   1  |   0   |   0  |   0  |   0 |   1     | 0   |   1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Every genre is separated by a | so we simply have to call the split function on |.**

```
[![artist_df\['genres'\] = artist_df.genres.str.split('|')
artist_df.head()][1]][1]
```

**First make a copy of the df into df.**

```
artists_with_genres = df.copy(deep=True)
```

**Then iterate through df, then append the artists genres as columns of 1s or 0s.**

**1 if that column contains artists in the genre at the present index and 0 if not.**

```
x = []

for index, row in artist_df.iterrows():
   x.append(index)
   for genre in row['genres']:
       artists_with_genres.at[index, genre] = 1

**Confirm that every row has been iterated and acted upon.**

print(len(x) == len(artist_df))

artists_with_genres.head(30)
```

**Filling in the NaN values with 0 to show that a artist doesn't have that column's genre.**

```
artists_with_genres = artists_with_genres.fillna(0)
artists_with_genres.head(3)
```

Comment: Have you looked at one hot encoding? pd.get_dummies() might just give you what you need.

Comment: No, I never heard of one hot encoding using pd.get_dummies() . But I will look into it

Comment: Trying but running into issue with it being a float.

Comment: use artist_df['genre'] = artist_df['genre'].astype(str)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this using `get_dummies`:

```
df['Genre'] = df['Genre'].str.split('|')
dfx = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df['Genre'].tolist()).stack()).sum(level=0)
df = pd.concat([df, dfx], axis=1).drop(columns=['Genre'])
print(df)

  Artist  Id  Blues  Hip-Hop  Jazz  Pop  Rap  Rb  Rock  Trap
0    Bob   1      1        0     1    0    0   0     0     0
1   Fred   2      0        0     1    0    0   0     1     0
2   Jeff   3      0        1     0    0    1   0     0     1
3    Amy   4      0        0     1    1    0   0     1     0
4   Mary   5      0        1     1    0    0   1     0     0
```

For detailed explanation, look here -> [Pandas column of lists to separate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657603/pandas-column-of-lists-to-separate-columns)

Comment: geting this error 'AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas'

Comment: I think it is becuase is a float64 artist_df['genre'].dtypes

dtype('float64')

Comment: How is Genre a float?

Comment: No clue maybe how i cleaned the data. I was able to convert to  a obj

Comment: artistId       int32
artistname    object
genre         object
demo          object
price         object
songs         object
url           object
bios          object
dtype: object

Comment: I am sure the code works, this is my 1st real project after only self learning from tutorials so alot of trial and error to get this far. I must of done something to get in wrong type.

Comment: Yes Genre is a pipe separated string based on what you pasted above. So it should work. Just make sure it is a pipe separated string.

Comment: should i do df3['genre'] = df3['genre'].astype(float) or df3['genre'] = df3['genre'].astype(str) to convert it

Comment: df3['genre'] = df3['genre'].astype(str)

Comment: thanks it worked but ended with two of each genre instead one. I will just keep reading and trying to see where i went wrong thanks.